# Problems pairing devices with my bluetooth adapter

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a problem with the Bluetooth. After formatting the PC (because of a ransomware) I have installed Windows 10 2004.

Right now I'm using a Bluetooth adapter from Amazon, which before formatting worked perfectly for me.
I have installed all the drivers with Driver Booster (I always use it and it has never given me problems) and from the device manager, I don't see anything strange.

The point is that when I want to connect the headset, they do not show on the connection list, not even the mobile.

From the mobile I can connect the headphones, so I do not know what the possible solution could be...

Comment: Did you try to set the headphones to pairing mode? Maybe when they are paired they are not discoverable

Comment: Yep, if I keep pressing the power off/on button for 4 seconds it start to be in pairing mode. Neithiner in this mode I can't make it work.

Comment: I understand. I see you answered your question already.. Glad to see it worked out

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that the Amazon seller sent me a message with a new drivers that are compatible with Windows 10. By default, the drivers didn't work.